# Send dynamically vars to smarty backend from frontend

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

I am trying to send dynamically a variable from `foreach` to smarty backend from smarty frontend but didn't work for all variables, it's shown only one... there are a way to accomplish that?
here's my code:

BACKEND:

```
    $allineamento = array();
    foreach($db->query("SELECT Fields FROM Tables WHERE Allineamento = :allineamento ORDER BY ID",array("allineamento"=>$smarty->getTemplateVars('all'))) as $row){
        $allineamento[] = $row;
    }
    $smarty->assign("allineamento",$allineamento);
```

FRONTEND:

```
    {foreach $maps as $r}
        {assign var="all" value="$r.ID"}
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <img src="img/locations/{$r.Immagine}" class="img-rounded">
                <a class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#panel-1" href="#panel-element-{$r.ID}">{$r.Nome}</a>
            </div>
            <div id="panel-element-{$r.ID}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                {foreach $allineamento as $a}
                    <div class="panel-body">{$a.Nome}</div>
                {/foreach}
            </div>
         </div>
    {/foreach}
```

The output is like this (Repeated fields):

```
1. FIELD 1        
     ° SECOND FOREACH A
     ° SECOND FOREACH B
     ° SECOND FOREACH C

 2. FIELD 2
     ° SECOND FOREACH A
     ° SECOND FOREACH B
     ° SECOND FOREACH C
```

Inseted of (different fields by the correct query in the backend):

```
1. FIELD 1        
     ° SECOND FOREACH A
     ° SECOND FOREACH B
     ° SECOND FOREACH C

 2. FIELD 2
     ° SECOND FOREACH D
     ° SECOND FOREACH E
     ° SECOND FOREACH F
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I may be mistaken, but I believe you have to pass your data as an array. So for example, if your front-end expects an array ( like `$allineamento`) then your back end must send this array as a child of your main `$data` array passed. Also you are not telling us what `$db` is but I am assuming it is a `mysqli` object, in that case, you need to use `fetch_assoc()` to obtain the data, then a `while`to iterate through each. Redo it like this:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT Fields FROM Tables WHERE Allineamento = :allineamento ORDER BY ID");


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $allineamento = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $allineamento[] = $row;
    }

    $data = array('allineamento' => $allineamento);

    $smarty->assign($data);
    // display it
    $smarty->display('index.tpl');
}
```

Comment: This will return an empty string...I've to check more

Comment: Sorry for late answare, no, it's not working ->db->query came from a class: 
https://github.com/WarriorDenB/PHP-MySQL-PDO-Database-Class
Really thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I believe youre trying to fetch all results in your table that matches the `allineamento` column to your value. Since you are not mentioning your table fields nor your table name I will change that to match what I think youre trying to do. Heres what I would do:

```
$db = new Db(); //this is your custom DB class
$smarty = new Smarty();

$vars = array(
    "allineamento" => "something"
);
$results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE Allineamento = :allineamento ORDER BY id", $vars);

$data = array('allineamento' => $results);
$smarty->assign($data);
// display it
$smarty->display('index.tpl');
```

Once the above is done, in your template (which I am calling `index.tpl`) you should now be able to parse as required:

```
{foreach $allineamento as $a}
    <div class="panel-body">{$a.Nome}</div>
{/foreach}
```